# How does the alliance's timer help in Games of War Fire Age work?

Tags: game-of-war-fire-age

I know you tap the help button on your queue to post your task in the aliance help so that anyone in the alliance can help you speed up the task.

Then you can visit posted aliance help requests to help other aliance members.

The thing is, my tasks don't seem to speed up, they just stay there all time long, and there is no noticeable change at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Alliance Help feature is broadcast to other players' screens.

Each person that notices and clicks "Help" will reduce your build/research/etc task by 1 minute or 1% whichever is greater.  If your alliance members arent online, and do not click the help button, that progress bar wont move.  It requires specific manual intervention by the other players and they might not be available when you are.

Comment: Yes, there should be a percentage, or the time for tasks that last hours or even days won't have a noticeable reduction  of time.

Comment: I have asked around online and apparently it is 1% or 1m, whichever is greater.  So a 7d task (10080m) would reduce by 1% which would equate to 100.8m.

Answer (score -1):

If you go to "Alliance" icon, then "Alliance Help" tab, you will see that you need a couple of people to help until it will complete i.e. 10/10.